# ZF2 asset-manager: html img path not resolved

Tags: php, html, image, zend-framework2, assets

I'm using zf2 [RWOverdijk/AssetManager](https://github.com/RWOverdijk/AssetManager) in a project built upon ZF2 Skeleton Application; it works fine for CSS and JS but can't resolve paths for IMG.

AssetManager configuration in Application/config/module.config.php contains:

```
namespace Application;
return array (
      .
      .
    // assets manager
    'asset_manager' => array(
        'resolver_configs' => array(
            'paths' => array(
                '__NAMESPACE__' => __DIR__ . '/../public',
            ),  // end asset manager paths
            'caching' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'cache'     => 'FilePath',
                    'options' => array(
                        'dir' => 'public',
                    )
                )
            ), // end caching               
        ), // end asset manager resolver
    ), // end assets manaApplicationger
      .
      .
);
```

The direcrory structure has:

- module

  - Application

    - config
    - public

      - assets

        - Application

          - css
          - js
          - images
    - src
    - view
- public

  - assets

    - Application

      - images

In the view template there is:

```
<?php
/* Include files */
$this->headScript()->appendFile($this->basePath() .'/assets/Application/js/dom-utils.js');
$this->headLink()->prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/assets/Application/css/home.css');
?>

<img src="<?php echo $this->basePath(); ?>/assets/Application/images/image.png" />
```

While it works fine for the CSS and Javascripts, it does not find the image unless i put it in the public/assets/Application/images directory.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently started working with the AssetManager module and in my case it works with images as expected.

Maybe it was a bug in the version you use (I am working with the current stable release 1.4.1), but it could also be a caching issue, just delete the files in your cache directory or temporarly disable the cache to see if it works.